# Invalid method Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List::_isSecure(Array (

Tags: error-log

Can you help me solve the problem with entering into product view page?

After updating magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.3 product pages not loading.

```
Invalid method Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List::_isSecure(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
0 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php(87): Varien_Object->__call('_isSecure', Array)
1 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php(87): Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List->_isSecure()
2 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag/list.phtml(39): Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List->getFormAction()
3 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
4 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
5 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
6 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
7 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
8 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('tags_tabbed', true)
9 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml(15): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('tags_tabbed')
10 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
11 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
12 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
13 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
14 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Additional.php(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
15 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/additional.phtml(27): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Additional->getChildHtmlList()
16 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
17 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
18 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
19 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
20 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
21 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_additio...', true)
22 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(416): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_additio...')
23 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
24 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
25 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
26 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
27 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
28 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
29 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
30 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
31 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(50): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
32 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
33 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
34 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
35 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
36 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
37 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
38 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
39 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
40 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
41 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
42 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
43 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
44 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
45 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
46 /var/www/vhosts/ledstore.fi/httpdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
47 {main}
```

Comment: Frontend and backend pages working well. Same on category view pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is an issue in magentno. I am not sure 100%.

For resolve the issue you ***need to rewrite the class*** [Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php#L27)

and from [`getFormAction()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php#L82) function you need to remove [`$this->_isSecure()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php#L87)  the class

You can use the *`Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()`* instead of  `$this->_isSecure()`

### Rewrite class:

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Tag_Product_List extends Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List
{
        public function getFormAction()
    {
        return Mage::getUrl('tag/index/save', array(
            'product' => $this->getProductId(),
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl(),
            '_secure' => Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()
        ));
    }

}
```

### config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
.....
  <global>
    <blocks>
    ....
            <tag>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Tag_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </tag>
    </blocks>
    ....
  </global>
</config>
```